# Swift UITableview display data from array

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift

I have a API that hands back a string of numbers based on a User. 
Once the API Request is made the function places the numbers into an Array.

```
var usernumbers = userResponse["Numbers"] as NSArray
```

> The debugger PrintLn shows:
>
> (   16467621007,
>           14152555613,
>           14046206007
>       )

When I hand this to UITableView, how do I split up the array so that each number goes into a separate cell? 
Ive tried:

```
let rowData: NSArray = tableData (usernumbers has been handed to table data)
```

I've tried:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = rowData.row (and all varieties of)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection methods? And you should be getting an error from `rowData.row`, since NSArray doesn't have a `row` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood  your problem correctly, this is what you are looking for,

```
cell.textLabel?.text = rowData[indexPath.row] as String
```

Edit:

```
let numberValue : NSNumber = rowData[indexPath.row] as NSNumber

 let text : String = numberValue.stringValue // add  nil check

 cell.textLabel?.text = text
```

You can directly assign like

`cell.textLabel?.text = numberValue.stringValue` - if you are sure there won't be a `nil` value

Comment: When I use 'rowData[indexPath.row] as String' I get "Swift dynamic cast failed" so Im not converting from the Array into a string correctly.

Comment: Currently the func tableView code is: 

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")
        
        let rowData: NSArray = tableData
       
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = rowData[indexPath.row] as String
        
        return cell

which fails on a 'Swift dynamic cast failed' error

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowData[indexPath.row]` where `indexPath.row` is the current cell starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

```
 private let data = Array(1...9)
```

then...

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return data.count
 }
```

and in your :

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {...
```

all the usual stuff.

```
  cell.textLabel?.text = String(format: "the magic number is : %.f", data[indexPath.row])
  }
```